# What is the most correct way to set limits of number of files on Linux?

Tags: linux, file, sockets, ulimit, sysctl

There are 3 ways to set limits of number of files and sockets on Linux:

1. `echo "100000" > /proc/sys/fs/file-max`
2. `ulimit -n 100000`
3. `sysctl -w fs.file-max=100000`

What is the difference?

What is the most correct way to set limits of number of files on Linux?

Comment: Offtopic but a good question. SO should allow easy migrating of such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sysctl` is an interface for writing to `/proc/sys` and so does the same as echoing directly to the files. Whereas `sysctl` applies across the whole filesystem, `ulimit` only applies to writes from the shell and processes started by the shell.